# Relationship between parent and child state in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ui-sref

I have a problem that is about parent state and child state.I have a button.When i click the button it opens a modal(state:`context.form`).It is okey but i have another state which is called `new`(new state is child of `context.form` state).What i want to do is when i click the button parent state and child state should bu executed together.I think problem is views code blog because instead of views I write another modal It is working

When modal is opened,child state should be shown in the ui-view field.
My code:

```
 .state('context.form', {
        parent: 'context',
        url: '/form',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
        },
        onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/entities/context/contextForm.html',
                controller: 'ContextDialogController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                abstract: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                windowClass: 'center-modal',
                size: 'md',
                resolve: {
                    entity: function () {
                        return {
                            name: null,
                            keywords: null,
                            createdAt: null,
                            status: null,
                            id: null
                        };
                    }
                }
            }) 
        }]
    })


      .state('new', {
            parent: 'context.form',
            url: ' ',
            data: {
                 authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
            },
            views: {
                'context.form@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/entities/context/context-dialog2.html',
                    controller: 'ContextDialogController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            },

        })
```

contextForm.html

```
<div class="" style="border-bottom:solid; border-bottom: solid;  height:25px;border-bottom-width: 1px;background-color: #337ab7">

    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-right:30px; color:white; margin-top:2px"
        aria-hidden="true" ng-click="vm.clear()">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myContextLabel" style="margin-left:20px; color:white"
        data-translate="eventinsightwebApp.context.home.createOrEditLabel">Create
        New Alarm Watch</h4>
</div>

<div id="form-container" style="margin-top:30px">

    <!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
    <form id="signup-form">

        <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
        <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
    </form>



</div>
```

context-dialog2.html

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-1"><label data-translate="" style="margin-left:-8px" for="field_publicWatch">Public:</label></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please try to add name to `ui-view` and add it to state 'new` in the `views` instead `context.form@`, also add url to new state `/form/x`; this is just for test, if you can make plunker.

Comment: Child state only loads when you enter into that. When you click on the button it's not going to the child state.

Comment: @RahulSharma I know.How do i pass child state?Parent state has contains contextForm and contextForm has ui-view.

Comment: @Maher Same problem continues

Comment: @Belhanda I think you need to redirect to the child on click. Because If without redirecting if you can load child data in parent then no use of child.

Comment: @RahulSharma how do i redirect? I add  abstract: true,line for redirecting.Also child is empty for this purpose.But it is not working.Maybe i don^t know redirecting

Comment: do one thing remove space'  ' from child route, because it creates URL like /form/<space>.

Comment: @RahulSharma I removed but not working

Comment: can you upload the screenshot?

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/nOlJ8B.png

Comment: I tested redirecting is working.Because in the debug process,child state is active.I think problem is views code blog